# Error while using matchQuery Elasticsearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I'm new to elasticsearch and Java.

I have a JSON object like

```
{
    "keyword":null,
    "size":[],
    "matchResults":
    { 
        "Data": ["first" "Second"]
    },
}
```

I want to search against "matchResults" field and expect output like below:

1. "Data" : "first"
2. "Data" : "Second"
3. "Data" : "first Second"
4. "Data" : "Second friend"

for getting these results I'm using matchQuery in Java code like this,

```
Map<String, List<String>> matchResults = request.getMatchResults();
if (matchResults != null) {
    for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> filter : matchResults.entrySet()) {  
        logger.info("key is" );
        List<String> values = filter.getValue();
        if (values != null) {
            query = query.filter(QueryBuilders.matchQuery(filter.getKey(),  values));
        }
    }
}
```

But this gives below error

```
{
"messages": [
    "{\"root_cause\":[{\"type\":\"parsing_exception\",\"reason\":\"[match] unknown token [START_ARRAY] after [query]\",\"line\":9,\"col\":23}],\"type\":\"parsing_exception\",\"reason\":\"[match] unknown token [START_ARRAY] after [query]\",\"line\":9,\"col\":23}"
],
"data": null,
"message": "{\"root_cause\":[{\"type\":\"parsing_exception\",\"reason\":\"[match] unknown token [START_ARRAY] after [query]\",\"line\":9,\"col\":23}],\"type\":\"parsing_exception\",\"reason\":\"[match] unknown token [START_ARRAY] after [query]\",\"line\":9,\"col\":23}"
}
```

Not sure what is causing this.